# to return _id as string instead of objectId with Model.find() mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

Im trying to get a list of records in mongoose with nestjs, the problem is when return the records the _id returns as empty object.
here is my code:

```
  const filters: any = {};
    if (typeof dto.searchTerm == 'string') {
      filters['username'] = { $regex: dto.searchTerm, $options: 'i' };
    }
    if (Object.values(UserRole).includes(dto.filterByUserRole)) {
      filters['role'] = dto.filterByUserRole;
    }
    const users = await this.userModel
      .find(filters, 'username email role bio createdAt updatedAt image')
      .limit(dto.size)
      .skip(dto.offset)
      .lean()
      .exec();

    const usersCount = await this.userModel.find(filters).count();
    return { content: users as any, count: usersCount };
```

I expected the return data like this:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "_id": "6416ea08b1019420467b3f20",
            ...the other field
        },
    ],
    "count": 1
}
```

but I got this response:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "_id": {},
            ...the other data
        },
    "count": 1
}
```

How to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your _id is being stored as a native ObjectId in Mongo.  Try accessing the "id" string field instead that Mongoose provides on the model, you will need to remove your use of .lean() for this to be present. This will depend on the versions of Mongo/Mongoose you are using, and how your schema is setup (for instance, you can switch off "id")

Comment: I'm facing the same issue here. One temporary suggestion could involve create a map to bring _id object as string. Something like: `users.map(user =>{ user._id = user._id.toString(); return user });` could create a temporary solution. However I'm still searching for the properly solution!

Comment: I recommend that you check the actual data in your response, compared to how its being _displayed_ (e.g. console.log or similar).  native ObjectId's can show as being "empty objects" because their native type can't be handled automatically. You may well have the _id field you want/need in your data.  But you should expect to have to use toString() to get a type of string in your code when you're using ObjectId's.  I have to say I wish I had chosen to use uuid's for mongo _id keys now!